# Homology question and isomorphism of chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

If for two chain complexes $(C_{},d_{}), (D_{},d_{}')$ we have $C_n\cong D_n$ for each $n$, does that mean the homology groups are isomorphic?

I tried approaching this, but I think I was only able to get the conclusion holds if we include the additional assumption that each isomorphism $C_n\rightarrow D_n$ takes $ker\partial_{n}$ to a subset of $im\partial_{n+1}$.

Comment: What are the homologies of $\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{id} \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If you have a genuine isomorphism of chain complexes, then the homology groups are isomorphic, but what you describe isn’t an isomorphism of chain complexes.

Comment: @ZhenLin what's a "genuine isomorphism of chain complexes"? moreover, under what additional assumptions would what I have described be a "genuine isomorphism of chain complexes"?

Comment: An isomorphism of chain complexes is a homomorphism of chain complexes (also called a chain map) that has an inverse.

Comment: Topologically, you could ask a similar question: if you have two simplicial complexes with the same number of $n$-simplices for each $n$, do they have isomorphic homology? (And as you might guess from the answers so far, the answer is also no.)

Comment: Note that the comment of @PedroBrunialti reveals something much more fundamental: one of the points of chain complexes is to relate a sequence of objects in a meaningful way, and forgetting about those maps will inevitably lead you astray. Since a map $V\to W$ is a complex (taking all other terms to be zero) your question boils down to: do there exist functions with different kernels of cokernels but the same domain and codomain? The answer is of course "Yes", as we learn in linear algebra.

Comment: A "genuine" morphism of complexes is a map $f : (C,d) \to (D,d')$ that commutes with the differentials, i.e. such that (using your notation) $f(dc) = d'f(c)$ for each $c\in C$. This involves the differentials of $C$ and $D$ (the important bit) in a non-trivial way, which an arbitrary map does not.